# Error scanning invalid input

Tags: java, input

This program needs to return 'Invalid Input' if anything other than a row between 0-4 is input, currently I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at ass.Puzzle.play(Puzzle.java:147)
at ass.Puzzle.main(Puzzle.java:18)
```

Comment: You might want to read it with `s.nextLine()` instead of `s.nextInt` and check if it is actually number and furtherone if it´s between 0-4 (i´d also include the condition `column >= 0`)

Comment: What it is the input that you are trying to read?

Comment: @Error404 Probably something that's not 1-4 (like `"bla"`). The problem lies in the `s.nextInt();` as correctly pointed out by _@KevinEsche_.

Comment: I need to supply an integer type to the method for it to work, changing it to s.nextLine() requires me to change the type to string so this will not work.

Comment: @RJB that´s why you try to parse the line to an `int` to check if it´s actually an integer. Afterwards you´re having an `int` again if it was succesfull.

Comment: @RJB my answer uses nextLine() to get a String but then converts it back to an integer. That way you can handle any bad input, from "5", to "xxxxxzzzz". You can still pass the integer to whatever method you need to. See below.

Comment: @RJB You can parse it later with `Integer.parseInt(string)` if you use `s.nextLine()` but I think the best approach it is to add a catch exception as @Mitiku put as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to catch the thrown exception

```
else if (input.equals("c")) {
    System.out.println("What column? (1-4)");

    try{
        int column = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
        if (column <= 4){
            rotateColumn(currentarr,column - 1);
            print(currentarr);
            b++;
        }
        else
           System.out.println("Invalid Input");
     }catch (InputMismatchException ex){
         System.out.println("Invalid Input");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the line and then parsing it as an int instead.

```
else if (input.equals("c")) {
    System.out.println("What column? (1-4)");
    String colStr = s.nextLine();
    try {
      int column = Integer.parseInt(colStr);
      if (column >= 1 && column <= 4){
        rotateColumn(currentarr, column - 1);
        print(currentarr);
        b++;
      }
      else
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
```

This will handle cases where the user enters something like "bad input" by catching an exception if it cannot parse their input as an integer.